# Set edittext using only ",0123456789" programmatically in Android?

Tags: java, android, digits

My question is this.

I can say in xml

```
android:digits="0123456789,"
```

But this time I've to it add trough java code.

```
customEditText.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("0123456789,"));
```

Doesn't work. Application gives me same result as android:InputType="number"

So is there any alternative way to say android:digits using java?

**EDITED**

So my question wasn't how to get `android:InputType="number"` using java.

My question is that how I can get `android:digits="0123456789,"` to be used with java.

At this point I don't care if the user can see characters. I just want my edittext field to accept only numbers from 0 to 9 and the decimal comma (,).

Because of the customEdittext is really a customized edittext I can't use xml atm.

Answer (score 11):

try `customEditText.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);`

Comment: Well I don't want to use number. Because then I can't get the decimal comma in use.

Answer (score 3):

```
EditText ed;
ed.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
```

also [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html) may help

Comment: Well I don't want to use number. Because then I can't get the decimal comma in use.

Comment: try to using inputfilter http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputFilter.html customEditText.setFilter(yourInputFilter);

Answer (score 1):

According to the Android documentation `TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL` should work http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html

However it doesn't, if you use only `TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL` the user will be able to input letters as well.

But by our luck, Haresh Chaudhary, provide the correct answer, both must be use, `TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER` and also `TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL`. I try hes solution and It worked.

Allthough I used setInputType instead of setRawInput:

```
yourEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `customEditText.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER)`?

Reference: [InputType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html)

Comment: Well I don't want to use number. Because then I can't get the decimal comma in use.

Comment: What version of android are you testing on? The DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("0123456789,") is working for me on 2.3, 4.0 and 4.1

Comment: galaxy s 2.3.3 and galaxy nexus 4.0.3

Answer (score -1):

Try to add `android:inputType="number"` in the xml layout to your `EditText` ([link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType))

Comment: Well this time I can't, because of the code. I've to do it using java only. And I wan't to have my edittext field to accept only numbers 0-9 and decimal comma (,).