# How to set the "InputType" of "EditText" that only can be inputed by "0123456789" and "." in java code

Tags: android, android-inputtype

How to set the "InputType" of  "EditText"  that only can be inputed by  "0123456789" and "." in java code?
I just konw I can make it by `android:digits="0123456789."` in XML,but I want to make it in jave code, I have tried to `editText.setInputType()`,but there is no this type.

Comment: EditorInfo.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL  maybe it works

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11519214/set-edittext-using-only-0123456789-programmatically-in-android?rq=1

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3ainputType

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this it worked for me.

```
editText.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("0123456789."));
```

Comment: right,and    `TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL`  is also useful    thank u